# OSGI : org/osgi/framework/ServiceEvent/MODIFIED not getting fired

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I have an OSGI (Felix) application in which there are few services created using declarative services.
e.g.

```
@Service
@Component(metatype = true)
public class SomeService implements IInterface {
@Property(value = "1")
private static final String SOME_PROP = "SOME_PROP";

@Modified
public void modified(Map<String, ?> inConfig)
{ //some code
}

@Activate
public void activate(Map<String, ?> inConfig)
{ //some code
}
```

Now after I start the framework I can see that the bundle corresponding to this service has been started.
If I try to change the property (SOME_PROP) through OSGI console, I only see an event with event topic **org/apache/felix/webconsole/plugins/event/internal/converter/ConfigurationEventConverter/CM_UPDATED** getting fired. I do not see **org/osgi/framework/ServiceEvent/MODIFIED** getting fired and hence modified method is not called and I can not see the new property value. Also one weird thing that I notice is that even though bundle **felix.scr** is listed in the installed bundles list, I can not see Bundle **org.apache.felix.scr started** event corresponding to it.

Any hints on why properties are not getting updated ?

Comment: Any thoughts from anyone ?

Comment: Which annotations do you use? Also what do you mean by "I try to change the property"? Is this a system property, or a config admin property, or something else? Which PID are you changing and does it match the name of the service component? Why exactly do you expect the ServiceEvent/MODIFIED to be fired anyway? Far too many unknowns and vague statements to be able to start offering possible answers.